# Tensorflow install fails with CUDA 8 RC

Tags: tensorflow

I understand that Cuda 8 is not yet supported by tensorflow but it is the only option which works on my Ubuntu 16.04 system.  (I can install 7.5 through the Ubuntu repositories but it does not create a cuda home directory so I can't use it for tensorflow .configure script even-though it works for everything else).  I tried to build it with the following command.

`bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`

I get this error.

```
ERROR: /home/chase/Desktop/tensorflow/tensorflow/stream_executor/BUILD:5:1: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/stream_executor:stream_executor' failed: crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc failed: error executing command third_party/gpus/crosstool/clang/bin/crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -fstack-protector -fPIE -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object ... (remaining 100 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc: In member function 'virtual bool perftools::gputools::cuda::CUDABlas::DoBlasGemm(perftools::gputools::Stream*, perftools::gputools::blas::Transpose, perftools::gputools::blas::Transpose, tensorflow::uint64, tensorflow::uint64, tensorflow::uint64, float, const perftools::gputools::DeviceMemory<Eigen::half>&, int, const perftools::gputools::DeviceMemory<Eigen::half>&, int, float, perftools::gputools::DeviceMemory<Eigen::half>*, int)':
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1683:22: error: 'CUBLAS_DATA_HALF' was not declared in this scope
       CUDAMemory(a), CUBLAS_DATA_HALF, lda,
                      ^
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc: In function 'cublasOperation_t perftools::gputools::cuda::{anonymous}::CUDABlasTranspose(perftools::gputools::blas::Transpose)':
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:406:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc: In function 'cublasFillMode_t perftools::gputools::cuda::{anonymous}::CUDABlasUpperLower(perftools::gputools::blas::UpperLower)':
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:417:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc: In function 'cublasDiagType_t perftools::gputools::cuda::{anonymous}::CUDABlasDiagonal(perftools::gputools::blas::Diagonal)':
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:428:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc: In function 'cublasSideMode_t perftools::gputools::cuda::{anonymous}::CUDABlasSide(perftools::gputools::blas::Side)':
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:439:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 118.926s, Critical Path: 115.25s
```

Does anyone know how to fix or work around this, or do I just need to wait for them to support CUDA 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2559) with the current version of TensorFlow. You can try patching in the code from this [pull request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/2556) to define the missing type  (`CUBLAS_DATA_HALF`), which is causing compilation to fail.